# Duplicate SafeMath in Solidity libraries

Tags: solidity

I'm working on a Solidity smart contract, and I'm importing both the openzeppelin-solidity library, as well as the chainlink library.

Both have the SafeMath library; I'm loading all the .sol files in Python.
When I try to compile (Python), I get the following error:

> TypeError: Member "div" not unique after argument-dependent lookup in
>   uint256

I got this error the moment I added the chainlink library, so I guess the problem is the duplicate SafeMath definition? Obviously I don't want to go change imports in either library.

How best to solve this?

Comment: For now I have solved it by duplicating SafeMath code, renaming it to SafeMathImport

in my contract I add:  

using SafeMathImport for uint256;

and in the SafeMathImport file I have renamed the functions.

Error gone. There's probably a better solution, but for now it works.

Comment: Just ran into the same issue... I don't really understand your solution, since I am not importing anything SafeMath. I just use openzeppelin's ERC20 and chainlink's ChainlinkClient.

Comment: Yes, I can't tell it off the top of my head, but I believe somewhere either in openzeppelin's code or in the chainlink code, SafeMath is imported.

Answer (score 1):

Chainlink repo now uses `safeMathChainlink` to avoid naming conflicts, so if you import that you’ll not have those issues.

Also, in v0.8 of solidity, safeMath as a whole is no longer needed